# how to set the parameters in pandas to draw a line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The figure contains my database and the target plot, and I want to plot it. The horizontal axis of the picture is the number 1-10, and the vertical axis is the corresponding value of AB. The line reflects the change of the values of AB and the two values within the range 1-10. However, there are some problems in parameter setting, mainly how to set the X axis and Y axis of the picture, so as to appear as shown in the picture, thanks.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

print(df)

ax = plt.gca()

df.plot(kind='bar',x='',y='',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='bar',x='',y='',color='red',ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Target Chart:

[image: target chart]

Answer (score 4):

Let's try with [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (`T`) and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
# Swap Row and Column Indexes and plot
# Set x and y lims
df.T.plot(ax=ax, ylim=[0, 20], xlim=[1, 10])
# Show y (horizontal) grid lines
ax.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

DataFrame Used:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'A': [13, 14, 15, 16, 15, 15, 18, 19, 10, 11],
    'B': [12, 13, 17, 19, 14, 16, 14, 13, 14, 16]
}, orient='index', columns=range(1, 11))
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
A  13  14  15  16  15  15  18  19  10  11
B  12  13  17  19  14  16  14  13  14  16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[13,14,15,16,15,15,18,19,10,11], 'B':[12,13,17,19,14,16,14,13,14,16]})

x0=np.array(list(range(10)))
x=x0+1

plt.plot(x, df['A'])
plt.plot(x, df['B'])
plt.show()
```